# List all sets of points that are enclosed by a circle with given radius

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

My problem is: Given N points in a plane and a number R, list/enumerate all subsets of points, where points in each subset are enclosed by a circle with radius of R. Two subsets should be different and not covered each other.

Efficiency may not be important, but the algorithm should not be too slow.

In a special case, can we find K subsets with most points? Approximation algorithm can be accepted.

Thanks,

Edit: It seems that the statement is not clear to understand. My bad!

So I restate my question as follows: Given N points and a circle with fixed radius R, use the circle to scan whole the space. At a time, the circle will cover a subset of points. The goal is to list all the possible subset of points that can be covered by such an R-radius circle. One subset cannot be a superset of other subsets.

Comment: where is the problem? what have you tried? what constraints? what language platform? What do you mean by too slow (10us, 2 years)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I get what you mean by 'not covered'. If you drop this, what you are looking for is exactely a Cech complex whose complexity is high, you wont have efficient algorithm if you dont have condition on the sampling (sampling should be sparse enough and R not too big otherwise you could have 2^n subsets with n your number of points). You have to enumerate all subsets and check if their minimal enclosing ball radius is lower than R. You can reduce the search to all subsets whose diameter is lower than R (eg pairwise distance lower than R) which may be sufficient in your case.

If 'not covered' for two subsets mean that one is not included into the other, you can have many different decompositions. One of interest is the alpha-complex as it can be computed efficiently in O(nlogn) in dimension 2-3 (I will suggest to use [CGAL](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_3/index.html#Chapter_3D_Alpha_Shapes) to compute it, you can also see what it means with pictures). If your points are high dimensional, then you will probably end up computing a Cech complex.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, we can assume that the enclosing circles considered pass through at least two points (ignoring the trivial cases of no points or one point and assuming that your motivation is maximizing density, so that you don't care if non-maximal subsets are omitted). Build a proximity structure (kd-tree, cover tree, etc.) on the input points. For each input point p, use the structure to find all points q such that d(p, q) ≤ 2R. For each point q, there are one or two circles that contain p and q on their boundary. Find their centers by solving some quadratic equations and then look among the other choices of q to determine the subset.